# When must you use array() to define an array?

Tags: php, arrays

In PHP I have seen the following types of coding:

```
my_array[] = "fish";
my_array[] = "book";
my_array[] = "chair";
```

Other times I have seen this done:

```
my_array = array();
my_array[] = "fish";
my_array[] = "book";
my_array[] = "chair";
```

What would be the purpose of "defining" an array in PHP with array() like above? Is it a good practice, if so why?

Comment: `my_array` is an array (PHP is intelligent to detect its type), You are pushing elements to that array.

Comment: did you mean `my_array = array();`?

Comment: @Musa Yes, typo. It's been corrected. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: look into weak vs strong typing.  Haters hate the php for this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to make sure your variable is defined before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare variables in PHP. this is just a better practice that improves readability and can prevent some errors on array using function you might use later on..